# What is meant by "The Lie derivative commutes with contraction"?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

This was stated recently in a GR course I am taking, and I found it also stated on Wikipedia (second [paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative)). I simply don't know what is meant by this. For a vector $X$ and 1-form $\eta$, I would define the contraction as

$$ \eta(X) $$

Whilst the Lie derivative of this quantity is

$$ \mathcal{L}_Y(\eta(X)) = (\mathcal{L}_Y\eta)(X) + \eta(\mathcal{L}_Y X) $$

By the Leibniz rule. So I can't see what "commutes" could mean in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $C$ as the contraction, so $\eta (X) = C(\eta \otimes X)$.

Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathcal{L}_Y(\eta(X)) &=  \mathcal{L}_Y (C (\eta \otimes X) \\
&= C  \mathcal{L}_Y(\eta \otimes X) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\text{Contraction commutes with Lie derivative}) \\
&= C (\mathcal{L}_Y \eta \otimes X + \eta \otimes \mathcal{L}_Y X) \ \ \ \ \ \ (\text{Leibniz rule}) \\
&= (\mathcal{L}_Y\eta)(X) + \eta(\mathcal{L}_Y X) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So what you wrote down is true because contraction commutes with Lie derivative.  (The rule is used so naturally that you don't even realize)

Comment: Very often one sees this contraction denoted by $\text{tr}$, as it's just the trace of $\eta \otimes X$ regarded as an endomorphism (or more precisely, as a field of endomorphisms) via the canonical bundle isomorphism $T^*M \otimes TM \cong End(TM)$.